# Json Output display from webservice call

Tags: json

I am pretty new to JSON / Jquery world so please bear with my ignorance.

I am trying to read an output from a Json data returned by webservice call like below :

My webservice call is here:

```
http://example.com/getPortfolioListByContact.json?component=C1&contactId=510297
```

This return the data as :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "PORTFOLIO_ID": 13495,
      "SUBSCRIPTION_ID": 1653,
      "STATUS": "ACTIVE",
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Now I am trying to get alert onthe Json Data returned as string and also want to get this as Parsed /

```
<script>
var parsed ; 
$.getJSON("http://example.com/getPortfolioListByContact.json?component=C1&contactId=510297", function(data){
    alert(data.SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
});
parsed = JSON.parse(data); 
alert(parsed) ; 
</script>
```

I am getting the response in Alert as "Undefined" . I may not be doing right handling the success handler . I want to get each value and specific value of the json data returned.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting the response in Alert as "Undefined".

**Reason :** You are trying to parse the API response out of the scope. As `data` object is only accessible in the promise returned by the API call.

Try this hope it will work as per your expectation **:**

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/getPortfolioListByContact.json?component=C1&contactId=510297", function(res) {
    var data = res.data;
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: I got that alert of entire json output But stringify I am missing the parsing . How can I get the data only for SUBSCRIPTION_ID ? JSON.parse is not working .May be I am missing something at gross level.

Comment: no need to use JSON.parse as data is coming as a parsed JSON only. you can directly access like this `res.data[0].SUBSCRIPTION_ID`

Comment: Thanks @Rohit . this is exactly what I need .

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `data` out side the scope.

```
<script>
var parsed ; 
var myData;
$.getJSON("http://example.com/getPortfolioListByContact.json?component=C1&contactId=510297", function(data){
 myData = data;
    alert(data.SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
});
parsed = JSON.parse(myData); 
alert(parsed) ; 
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but Unfortunately still throwing undefined and getting only one Alert .By the way adding below in top of the script call . <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>